# How to create/drop function within stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have created a stored procedure where I an looping through data and inserting records based on the data. The inserts have the same format, but the data changes slightly.

The decision making is handled with IF/ELSE statements, and I have a dozen or so `INSERT` queries (one for each decision).

I'd like to put the `INSERT` into a function that I can just call with the variables that change.

I would like to create the function at the beginning of the stored procedure, and then `DROP` it at the end.

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[DataParser]
AS
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InsertFunc]
        (@Number VARCHAR(40),
         @Line_No INT,
         @Topic VARCHAR(30),
         @Note VARCHAR(4099),
         @Bool VARCHAR(1))
    RETURNS bit
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Processing (Number, Line_No, Topic, Note, Activation_Date, Mandatory)
        VALUES (@Number, @Line_No, @Topic, @Note,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1), @Mandatory)

        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    ...
    ...
    Decision tree
    ...
    ...
    InsertFunc(@oid, @lidCounter, 'StrVal1', @strVar2, 'Y')
```

Right now it will not let me save the stored procedure, and if I try to create the function outside of the stored procedure, I get the following error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure DataParser, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 23]
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do DML in functions. Use procedures for that.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do here ? Why do you want to create a function inside a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that in SQL Server you cannot perform INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE actions within a function.

Although I don't recommend an approach where you are creating and removing stored procedures dynamically, if you try your approach creating a stored procedure instead of a function it should work.

Comment: I changed it to CREATE PROCEDURE, removed the RETURNS bit, and RETURN @@ROWNUM.  I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'." and "Must declare the scalar variable "@Import_Set_Number"."

Comment: Can you please update the question again? With what you have mentioned here

Answer (score 1):

Below is stored procedure that may help you.

Create Table #Temp
  (
          Number varchar(40),
          Line_No INT,
          Topic VARCHAR(30),
          Note VARCHAR(4099),
          Bool VARCHAR(1),
          Activation_Date datetime,
          Mandatory varchar(10)
  )

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertDataIntoTable]
    (@Number VARCHAR(40),
     @Line_No INT,
     @Topic VARCHAR(30),
     @Note VARCHAR(4099),
     @Bool VARCHAR(1),
     @Mandatory varchar(4))

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Number, Line_No, Topic, Note, Activation_Date, Mandatory)
    VALUES (@Number, @Line_No, @Topic, @Note,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1), @Mandatory)


END
```